# Onchange combobox, change value of another textbox

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Im new in knockout.js

i want to change the value of Salary when change combobox of EmployeeCode, but my value in textbox of Salary is not change to 12.

Here is my Code

My JS:

```
var jsDetail = function (data) {
        this.Code = ko.observable(data.Code || '');
        this.SalaryCode = ko.observable(data.SalaryCode || '');
        this.EmployeeCode = ko.observable(data.EmployeeCode || '');
        this.WorkDay = ko.observable(data.WorkDay || 0);
        this.OvertimeWorkDay = ko.observable(data.OvertimeWorkDay || 0);
        this.Salary = ko.observable(data.Salary || 0);
        this.MealAllowance = ko.observable(data.MealAllowance || 0);
        this.OvertimePay = ko.observable(data.OvertimePay || 0);
        this.TotalMealAllowance = ko.observable(data.TotalMealAllowance || 0);
        this.TotalOvertimePay = ko.observable(data.TotalOvertimePay || 0);
        this.TotalPay = ko.observable(data.TotalPay || 0);
        this.Deleted = ko.observable((data.IsDeleted || 'false').toString());
    };

    var jsSalaryViewModel = function (json) {
        ko.mapping.fromJS(json, {
            SalaryDetails: {
                create: function (option) {
                    return new jsDetail(option.data);
                }
            }
        }, this);

        this.addNewDetail = function () {
            this.SalaryDetails.push(new jsDetail({}));
            $("#properties tbody").trigger('sortupdate');
        }.bind(this);

        this.removeDetail = function (detail) {
            this.SalaryDetails.remove(detail);
        }.bind(this);


        this.employeeChange = function (detail) {
            console.log(detail.Salary);
            datail.Salary = 12;
        }.bind(this);
    };

    var viewmodel = new jsSalaryViewModel(@Html.Raw(json));
    ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
```

My Combobox and textbox :

```
        <select data-bind="event: { change : $root.employeeChange }, value:EmployeeCode, attr : {name: 'SalaryDetails[' + $index() + '].EmployeeCode'}" class="form-control">
            <option value=""> </option> 
            <option value="1"> One </option> 
        </select>
        <input type="number" data-bind="value:Salary, attr : {name: 'SalaryDetails[' + $index() + '].Salary'}" class="form-control" />
```

Please help me.

Comment: Pay attention to the JS errors in the browser console. You have a typo in your code. `datail` instead of `detail`.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a few things wrong with your code and it's hard to list them all without turning this answer into a knockout tutorial.

There already is a [knockout tutorial](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) and I am convinced that you should take it.

Also stop by the fantastic [documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/introduction.html). Your current attempt indicates a lack of basic understanding of how the library is supposed to work and that's something you absolutely need to fix before writing more code.

The most prominent thing that's wrong is that you try to use jQuery to solve part of the problem. Don't do that. Leave jQuery out of the picture. You typically don't need it in a knockout application and it absolutely should never appear inside your viewmodels. No jQuery DOM updating, no jQuery event handling from inside a viewmodel. No jQuery inside the HTML view, either.

What follows is a working snippet of what I think you want to do, reduced to the minimum. There are quite a few changes, both in the JS vievmodel and in the HTML view. Please compare thoroughly to your code.

```js
function SalaryDetail(data) {
  data = data || {};
  this.EmployeeCode = ko.observable(data.EmployeeCode || '');
  this.Salary = ko.observable(data.Salary || 0);
};

function SalaryEditor(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.currentDetail = ko.observable();
  
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {
    SalaryDetails: {
      create: function(option) {
        return new SalaryDetail(option.data);
      }
    }
  }, self);

  self.addNewDetail = function() {
    self.SalaryDetails.push(new SalaryDetail());
  };

  self.removeDetail = function(detail) {
    self.SalaryDetails.remove(detail);
  };

  self.employeeChange = function(detail) {
    self.currentDetail().Salary(12);
  };
};

var viewmodel = new SalaryEditor({
  SalaryDetails: [
    {EmployeeCode: '12345', Salary: 40},
    {EmployeeCode: '23456', Salary: 50},
    {EmployeeCode: '34567', Salary: 60},
    {EmployeeCode: '45678', Salary: 70}
  ]
});
ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="
    value: currentDetail,
    options: SalaryDetails,
    optionsText: 'EmployeeCode',
    optionsCaption: 'select detail...'
" class="form-control">
</select>

<span data-bind="with: currentDetail">
  <input type="number" data-bind="value: Salary" class="form-control" />
  <button data-bind="click: $root.employeeChange">Reset Salary</button>
  <button data-bind="click: $root.removeDetail">Remove Detail</button>
</span>
<button data-bind="click: $root.addNewDetail">Add Detail</button>

<hr>Viewmodel state:
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function SalaryDetail(data) {
  data = data || {};
  this.EmployeeCode = ko.observable(data.EmployeeCode || '');
  this.Salary = ko.observable(data.Salary || 0);
};

function SalaryEditor(data) {
  var self = this;

  self.currentDetail = ko.observable();
  
  ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {
    SalaryDetails: {
      create: function(option) {
        return new SalaryDetail(option.data);
      }
    }
  }, self);

  self.addNewDetail = function() {
    self.SalaryDetails.push(new SalaryDetail());
  };

  self.removeDetail = function(detail) {
    self.SalaryDetails.remove(detail);
  };

  self.employeeChange = function(detail) {
    self.currentDetail().Salary(12);
  };
};

var viewmodel = new SalaryEditor({
  SalaryDetails: [
    {EmployeeCode: '12345', Salary: 40},
    {EmployeeCode: '23456', Salary: 50},
    {EmployeeCode: '34567', Salary: 60},
    {EmployeeCode: '45678', Salary: 70}
  ]
});
ko.applyBindings(viewmodel);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout.mapping/2.4.1/knockout.mapping.min.js"></script>

<select data-bind="
    value: currentDetail,
    options: SalaryDetails,
    optionsText: 'EmployeeCode',
    optionsCaption: 'select detail...'
" class="form-control">
</select>

<span data-bind="with: currentDetail">
  <input type="number" data-bind="value: Salary" class="form-control" />
  <button data-bind="click: $root.employeeChange">Reset Salary</button>
  <button data-bind="click: $root.removeDetail">Remove Detail</button>
</span>
<button data-bind="click: $root.addNewDetail">Add Detail</button>

<hr>Viewmodel state:
<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON($root, null, 2)"></pre>
```